# How can I display two discrete plots into one?

Tags: plotting, discrete

I have two criteria for the domain of $n\in\mathbb{N}$:

For all ***even $n$***, I want to use the constant function $f(n)=5$

For ***odd $n$***, I want to use the function $g(n)=9 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n^2}{5}\right)$

And then I want to have one plot for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and if possible, to join the adjacent numbers.

Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[n_] := (1 - Mod[n, 2]) 9 Sin[Pi n^2/5] + Mod[n, 2] 5

DiscretePlot[f[n], {n, 1, 20}, Joined -> True, Filling -> None, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"Point", .02}]
```

[image]

```
DiscretePlot[{f[n], f[n]}, {n, 1, 20}, Joined -> {False, True}, 
 Filling -> 1 -> Axis, PlotMarkers -> {"Point", .02}]
```

[image]

```
DiscretePlot[{f[n], f[n]}, {n, 1, 20}, Joined -> {False, True}, 
 Filling -> 1 -> Axis, PlotMarkers -> {"Point", .02}, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Opacity[1]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (If[OddQ[Round[#]], Red, Blue] &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
f[n_?EvenQ] := 5;
f[n_?OddQ] := 9*Sin[(Pi*n^2)/5];
ListPlot[Table[f[n], {n, 1, 20, 1}], Joined -> True, 
 MeshStyle -> {Red}, Mesh -> {Range[1, 20, 2]}]
```

To distinguish  two types of the points, one way is

```
f[n_?EvenQ] := 5;
f[n_?OddQ] := 9*Sin[(Pi*n^2)/5];
ListPlot[Table[f[n], {n, 1, 20, 1}], 
 Mesh -> {Range[1, 21, 2], Range[2, 22, 2]}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #1 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red], Blue}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Another way is

```
evenColor = 
  Table[{n, Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}, {n, 1, 21, 2}];
oddColor = 
  Table[{n, Directive[Blue, PointSize[Large]]}, {n, 2, 22, 2}];
meshColor = Join[evenColor, oddColor];
f[n_?EvenQ] := 5;
f[n_?OddQ] := 9*Sin[(Pi*n^2)/5];
ListPlot[Table[f[n], {n, 1, 20, 1}], Joined -> True, 
 Mesh -> {meshColor}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
Show[
 DiscretePlot[5, {n, 0, 20, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 DiscretePlot[9 Sin[Pi n^2/5], {n, 1, 20, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ListLinePlot[
  Table[
   {n, Piecewise[{{5, EvenQ[n]}, {9 Sin[Pi n^2/5], True}}]}, {n, 0, 20}], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Gray]],
 PlotRange -> Full
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately, I get an error. The plot is not shown.

Comment: @charmin what is the error? I don't get any error and I'm on 12.1.1.0 on Windows10

Comment: A red box containing "The specified setting for the option GraphicsBoxOptions, PlotRange cannot be used."

Comment: @charmin must be a bug in your version. Try this instead: `Show[DiscretePlot[5, {n, 0, 20, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {-6, 6}], 
 DiscretePlot[9 Sin[Pi n^2/5], {n, 1, 20, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ListLinePlot[
  Table[{n, Piecewise[{{5, EvenQ[n]}, {9 Sin[Pi n^2/5], True}}]}, {n, 
    0, 20}], PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Gray]]]`

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, it works :)